# Xcode: Build error: tried to link DWARF for unsupported file:

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4

I've changed something in my project settings and now when I run this project to build and debug I get build error:

**GenerateDSYMFile error: tried to link DWARF for unsupported file: *"correct path to my application executable here"***

but! when I press RUN once more it works like a charm and my app starts in Simulator.
so I need press cmd-R twice every time to debug my app.

it was normal in previous version of my project so I don't know what changes I've made %)
all my other projects works fine and I can just recreate this project, but I want to figured it out - what trigger this error. I tried to ask this question on Apple devforums but without any success.

any help here? thx )

ps this error shows as Xcode3 as Xcode4

Answer (score 2):

There is `same file name` as your `project name` in `bundle` so get `rid` of that `file` by `renaming` it and use accordingly.

`Clean` the `project` and run the project. Good to go.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you figured out what the problem was, had the same thing happen to me. I had made a text file called the same name as my project - when I got rid of that it fixed it.

Comment: Same here, though I had to clean and rebuild deleting the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing under Build Options > Debug Information Format. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it when I tried to run my app in the simulator.
Xcode said ATTACHING TO PROCESS but hung.
So had to kill XCode and restart.
When I ran project again it built ok but when I said RUN it got that link error.

I fixed it by deleting the app in the Simulator and hit run again and it worked.

Comment: im guessing the space messes up the build paths somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In my case It was a plist file causing the error.

I renamed the file and updated Info.plist File in Target Build Settings and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error: *"error: tried to link DWARF for unsupported file: /Volumes/..."*

This error wasn't shown before up until I changed to Xcode 6 in my Jenkins server. Before we had the same setting of the App and was building without any problem.

I was building the app as Realase version via Jenkins and I had the setting to build with the following configuration "-configuration Release" and the parameter "Debug Information Format" in Build Setting of the app was set to DWARF-with-dSYM.

In order to solve this error I changed in the targets in Xcode in Build Settings in the parameter "Debug Information Format" to DWARF only and I didn't get any error from Jenkins.

The apple developer documentation says this regarding the different values of this parameter:

**DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT (Debug Information Format)**

**Description:** Identifier. Identifies the format used to store the binary’s debug information.

***Values:***

*stabs:* Use the Stabs format and place the debug information in the binary.

**dwarf:** Use the DWARF format and place the debug information in the binary.

**dwarf-with-dsym:** Use the DWARF format and place the debug information in a dSYM file.

**Default value:**
dwarf

**Prerequisite for:**
“GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION (Separate PCH Symbols).”

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html